# extracting all tags(duplicates also) with specified name from xmltype column in sql

Tags: sql, xml, duplicates, extract

i want to extract a tag from an xml and insert into another table.
this XML is having different name spaces hence i use local-name() to fetch the tag which i want.
but some times there are multiple tags with same name. hence its failing with EXACTFETCH RETURNS MULTIPLE NODES. when multiple tags are existed i want to consider both instead of ignoring the second occurence.

```
source_table(id, payload):
id : 10
payload : 
<root>
  <name>john</name>
  <status>
    <statuscode>1</statuscode>
    <statusmessage>one</statusmessage>
    <statuscode>2</statuscode>
    <statusmessage>two</statusmessage>
  </status>
</root>
```

i want to extract stauscode and message and insert into another table

```
destination_table(id,name,statuscode,message)
output
10,john,1,one
10,john,2,two
```

below is the query i used

```
select id, 
   extract(payload, '//*[local-name()="name"]'),
   extract(payload, '//*[local-name()="statuscode"]'),
   extract(payload, '//*[local-name()="statusmessage"]')
from source_table;
```

i can get first occurence or second occurence by specifying [1] or [2] but i need both the stauscodes to be displayed like below

```
10,john,1,one
10,john,2,two
```

any help here

Comment: @ajaykasetty, if my answer is helpful, please vote up and/or mark as accepted thx!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you need: Just past this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt it for your needs:

This solution assumes, that the status codes are sorted (as in your example 1,2,...). If this could occur in random order, just ask again...

Short explanation: The CTE "NameAndCode" brings up the name and the statuscodes. The ROW_NUMBER-function give us the node's index. This index I use to fetch the right message.

One more hint: If you can change the XML's format, it would be better to make the message an attribut of statuscode or to have it as subnode...

```
DECLARE @xmlColumn XML='<root>
  <name>john</name>
  <status>
    <statuscode>1</statuscode>
    <statusmessage>one</statusmessage>
    <statuscode>2</statuscode>
    <statusmessage>two</statusmessage>
  </status>
</root>';


WITH NameAndCode AS
(
    SELECT @xmlColumn.value('(/root/name)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Name
          ,x.y.value('.','int') AS Statuscode
          ,x.y.query('..') XMLNode
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.y.value('.','int')) AS StatusIndex
    FROM @xmlColumn.nodes('/root/status/statuscode') AS x(y)
)
SELECT *
      ,XMLNode.value('(/status[1]/statusmessage[sql:column("StatusIndex")])[1]','varchar(max)') 
FROM NameAndCode
```